# How to go thoroughly apex class body?

Tags: apex, class

I am developing code review tool to do the code review of apex class.

So, here i need to **go through line by line of Apex class body** and then needs to perform some analysis.

please give suggestion on this.

Comment: You are writing an app to analyze others code but do not know how to write the code to do that which would be the same code you are analyzing?  What have you tried so far? Question is currently to broad.

Comment: i wrote code and now want to get through the content of body. if you have suggestion tell me.

Comment: I am the creator of [Clayton](http://www.clayton.io) - the code analysis bot for Salesforce - and I can tell you that this not a simple task at all. Don't reinvent the wheel, just something that is already there. If you need a code free solution try Clayton or CodeScan, if you want to write your own rules you should consider extending PMD.

Answer (score 3):

You can get body of yours apex classes direct in Apex code through standard object ApexClass ([SOAP API Developer Guide)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_apexclass.htm)

```
List<ApexClass> apexClassList = [SELECT Name, Body, ApiVersion
                                 FROM ApexClass 
                                 WHERE NamespacePrefix = null];
```

You get body as String and then you can work with it how you want.

Also, please look on this tools, maybe they can help you:

1. [PMD](https://github.com/pmd/pmd)
2. [{/code.scan} Code Analysis for Salesforce](https://www.code-scan.com/)
3. [Force.com Security Source Scanner](https://security.secure.force.com/security/tools/forcecom/scanner)
4. [ApexMetrics - Code Climate engine for Salesforce.com Apex](https://github.com/Up2Go/codeclimate-apexmetrics)
5. [Apex security scanner - Eclipse Plug-in](https://www.apexscanner.com/EclipsePlugin/EclipsePluginRequest.aspx)
6. [CodeScan Apex PMD Eclipse Plugin](http://codescan.villagechief.com/eclipse/)
7. [Clayton](https://www.clayton.io)

Comment: Hey there! I have created a cloud based code analysis tool that I think it's worth adding to your list. https://www.clayton.io/

Comment: @Lorenzo Okay, no problem!